# Child elements hover/link in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to get some elements to move slightly when the user mouses over them (they form buttons on a navbar). However, my code doesn't seem to work. The text in the boxes should also be clickable but that doesn't seem to work either. Here's the code:

```
#navbar {
position: relative;
width: max-width;
height: auto;
margin-left: 2%;
}

.nav_tab{
background-image: url('dark_exa.png');
border: 2px dashed grey;

/* rounded borders of 5px in firefox */
-moz-border-radius:10px;  

/* rounded borders of 5px in chrome and other browsers */
-webkit-border-radius:10px;  

/* rounded borders of 5px in browsers that support css3 */
border-radius:10px;

/* shadows for different browsers */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black, 2px 1px 4px 4px rgba(10,10,0,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black 2px 1px 4px 4px rgba(10,10,0,.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10,10,0,.5);
position: relative;
height: auto;
width:20%;
z-index: -1;
margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
top: -30px;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav_tab:hover{
position: relative;
top: +5px;
}

h1 {
font-size:40px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "Gabriela";
margin: 20px;
margin-top: 130px;
}
h2 {
font-size:30px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "Gabriela";
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div class="nav_tab"><h2><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Zues</a></h2></div>
<div class="nav_tab"><h2>Jack</h2></div>
<div class="nav_tab"><h2>Denise</h2></div>
<div class="nav_tab"><h2>Joel</h2></div></div>
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, though I presume it's some kind of parent-child issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make a demo so that its easy for all to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not clickable because you gave the `.nav_tab` class a negative `z-index` value just adjust it to a value => 0 and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index: -1;` of the `.nav_tab` css it's your problem, it makes the container behind the page so any mouse event won't work (hover, pointer, etc) remove it and your ready to go:
see the jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/QmVFR/64/